# How to export a query result into several csv files by their date? (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

So I have a database of a bunch of log files. They each have a date ranging over the span of a few months. The query I run returns a result of a few hundred per date.

Saving everything into one csv file is too big (About 60 000 rows) to use in excel like I want to.
So I want to create a csv file for each day, so 0401.csv 0402.csv 0403.csv and so on...

Below is a code I use to count the amount of entries in each date

```
      SELECT CAST(Created_at AS DATE), COUNT(*) AS Count FROM tbTickets
      WHERE Created_at BETWEEN '2020/04/01 00:00:00' AND '2020/08/01 23:59:59'
AND (lots of other conditions here)

      GROUP BY CAST(Created_at AS DATE)
      ORDER BY 1;
```

The above returns something like this

```
2020-04-01            150
2020-04-02            165
...
```

So what I want to do is save those 150 entries (not the number 150, but the 150 rows with all their columns) into their respective file.

The above code is using GROUP BY, and I am not advanced enough at SQL to know if I can use this to export files. In general in programming I should be able to loop through all the rows and count the amount of dates, order them by date, set the start date to the earliest and loop through all the rows and save the rows to their respective file. Does anyone know how to do this in SQL? Thanks!

Comment: A 60,000 row CSV isn't really very big, why is that "too large"? Also, you should really stop using ordinal positions in your `ORDER BY` clause. [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: Stop using localized date literals too, or storing dates in string fields instead of using the correct type. It's quite possible the delay is caused because the server has to scan all those string values and parse them to dates before it can filter and order them without taking advantage of any indexes. Use `date` if you want to store dates, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` if you want to store data and time

Comment: @Larnu it's too big because when I try to open a similar file with around 4000 rows, it takes a minute to open in Excel. Meaning this would take about 10-15 minutes and be hard to navigate. It's got 30 columns and is full of Japanese characters, including a huge text field with lots of information (error logs, etc).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, I realize that and will work on these kind of things after I have established that the processes I need to do are going to work. There's currently no performance issues in the database itself, I am just wondering how to export data into several files.

Comment: You'll need to implement an ETL process to do this. For example using SSIS to loop through the datasets per day, or powershell and `bcp`. There are plenty of options out there,

Comment: @sebjsv not like this. This isn't how SQL the language, or SQL Server works. You *did* call a 60K CSV too big though, so there's definitely a performance problem somewhere. 60K rows is tiny

Comment: What I do in similar situations is a) Not use varchar, use `date` b) Not use localized dates, I use parameterized queries in C# and pass strongly-typed `DateTime` parameters and c) Use a C# program to retrieve what I want and write it out to separate files as needed. I use `EPPlus` to create real Excel files directly instead of going through CSV

Comment: Another possibility is (after using the correct types and dates) to use a PowerShell script to retrieve the data and write it out with `export-csv`. There are several ways to query, from `Invoke-Sqlcmd` to `Read-SqlTableData` or writing ADO.NET code. There's even an [Export-Excel](https://dfinke.github.io/powershell/2019/07/31/Creating-beautiful-Powershell-Reports-in-Excel.html) in a separate module

Comment: Another possibility is to use `bcp` in a powershell script. In all cases, the script calculates the appropriate date ranges and types, executes the query for all ranges and exports the data to `csv` or `xlsx`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, creating a program that does this might be the better solution indeed. I'm very new to SQL still but have experience with VB.NET which it seems like EPPlus supports so I'll check that out, thank you!

Comment: I always ask... why are you opening 60K rows in excel? Are you doing some analysis that would be better done in another tool like.. a database? or Power BI?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Probably... I'm in Japan and they don't like changing things. Excel is the favorite thing in their lives.

Comment: Understood.... it's not just Japan it's everywhere. I see this every day - people who can't evolve their processes. BTW you don't need EPPlus to generate a CSV. A CSV is just a text file. If I was to undertake this I would use powershell but use whatever platform is quickest for you